# Java ServerSocket closed port

Tags: java, port, serversocket

I am making a simple Server application.I wanted to know if there is any way to know if the port that user enters in the application ,in order to make new ServerScoket that's listening to this port , is closed?Say,someone enters port 5000 that's closed,is there any way to check it and inform the user that he/she is trying to use closed port?

I want to do something like this :

```
int port = Integer.parseInt(portField.getText()); // the port that users enter in my application

if ( port.isClosed() ) {
    System.out.println("This port is closed.Try another!");
}
```

isClose is a method that checks whether the port is closed or not.By "closed" i mean that the user hasn't done port forwarding.

Comment: I think you need more thought it the structure of your question. It's unclear the flow you are trying to accomplish.  Please also consider what you have looked at and done - as it may provide others insight in how best to answer your question.

Comment: @PaulBastide I don't find anything unclear here. Perhaps you should refrain from commenting on things you don't understand.

Comment: @EJP the question has been updated since I commented. I suggest you refrain from assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Java. You could write a WMIC command or something that examines the local firewall rules, but if the port is closed by an external router even that won't work. You should *choose* a *fixed* local port *yourself* and *instruct* the user that they must open the port, via whatever means are locally applicable.

Comment: Thank you,though it's sad that i can't check it!.Thank you very much for this useful information.

Comment: You should consider upvoting and accepting answers you find useful here. 'Sad` is not a technical term. Sometimes life is just the way it is.